# How to retrieve data from specific row SQLiteAssetHelper

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

how to retrieve specific data by their Id and display them in textview? instead of retrieving the data and display all the data in listview. please help!

public class KaikaiProfileActivity extends ListActivity {

```
private Cursor animals;
private MyDatabase db;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    db = new MyDatabase(this);
    animals = db.getAnimals(); // you would not typically call this on the main thread

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, 
            animals,
            new String[] {"animalName","animalPersonality"}, 
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2});;


    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);






}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    animals.close();
    db.close();
}
```

// retrieve all data
how to retrieve the data from specific row?
public Cursor getAnimals() {

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String [] sqlSelect = {"0_id", "animalName", "animalInfo","ImageName","animalGender","animalDOB",
                             "animalDOB", "animalBirthPlace", "animalPersonality", "animalFeatures", "animalFood", "animalPastTime"
    };
    String sqlTables = "AnimalInfo";

    qb.setTables(sqlTables);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null,
            null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    return c;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `c.moveToPosition(int index)` in place of `c.moveToFirst()` to get record at that particular index

For example, if you want to return first record, use `c.moveToPosition(0)`, for second record use `c.moveToPosition(1)` and so on

If you want to retrieve by column value then use `qb.appendWhere("<colname>=<value>") ;`